# Using scanf in a while loop to keep asking the user for a number until a number is entered

Tags: c, scanf

So I'm trying to keep asking the user for a number until a number is entered and then print the result but I can't get scanf to be called after the first iteration. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int main(void) {

    int x;

    int entered_an_number = 0;

    while(!(entered_an_number)) {

        printf("Please enter a number: \n");

        if(scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
            entered_an_number = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("You entered: %d \n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer, like the answer to most `scanf` questions, is *don't use `scanf`*. Use `fgets` to read a line of input and then scan inside that input, e.g.:

```
    char input[128];
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    if(sscanf(input, "%d", &x) == 1) {
        entered_an_number = 1;
    }
```